# Reuse mockup-pattern for anonymous theme

Tags: plone

I want to reuse momentjs (mockup-patterns-moment) in the frontend theme, but it does not work

What I already tried:

```
require([
    'example.theme',
    'mockup-patterns-moment'
]);
```

in Ressource-registry, or direct in theme .html nothing worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

This pattern is already part of the Plone default bundle, so you do not have anything to declare to use it, just use the proper markup:

```
<span class="pat-moment"
     data-pat-moment="format:calendar">2016-06-16</span>
```

Comment: Yes, but not for the frontend/anonymous theme, there i have not Plone default bundle (neither js nor css)

Comment: I guess you mean your Diazo theme is not inserting the Plone default bundles in your pages. If so, you cannot really use the mockup patterns (or maybe you could if you create your own mockup bundle containing the specific patterns you want, but it sounds much simpler to get the default bundles).

Comment: Wait, I thought moment only shipped in the logged-in bundle?  Fixing that's going to require an add-on author to ship another bundle?

Comment: I think moment is in `plone-compiled.js`, but even if it was in `plone-logged-in-compiled.js`, you could just fix that in the registry easily, no need to create a specific bundle.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes I mean the Diazo theme... shouldn't/couldn't it be easy to use  (all) patterns in the Diazo theme - "ithout great efforts?

Comment: Just make sure to inject the Plone script tags in your theme like this: <after css:theme-children="head" css:content="head script" /> and all the patterns will be available

Answer (score 0):

In your theme html file, you should be able to do something like this

```
<script>
    require([
        'mockup-patterns-moment'
    ]);
</script>
```

Then do, as @ebrehault suggests

```
<span class="pat-moment"
     data-pat-moment="format:calendar">2016-06-16</span>
```

See the answer here: https://community.plone.org/t/how-to-make-pat-moment-available-to-anonymous-users/1577